# Hive Partitioning for a big table

Tags: hive, partitioning

i have a hive table that has three columns.

```
origin zip, destination zip, miles
```

most of the queries on this table will have a where clause with the two fields

```
origin zip, destination zip
```

and selecting the

```
miles
```

what is the best way to partition the table or how to improve the select performance? the table has 2billion rows and orc table.

thanks

Comment: you can use bucketing instead of partitioning as well, see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL+BucketedTables

Comment: Try origin_zip range partitioning using state name (see ranges here: http://www.aip2.com/zip2.htm ) + bucketing by zip_destination. Build zip_range_dim and use it in map join for lookup to get range_name (state).